# Javascript function call scoping

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I have the following (simplified) java script, html and included java script(js) file.  My issue is that I get an error that the method does not exist on the syncData function call.  I get the fact that I can call the sync function because it is in the scope of window.Main but why can't I call syncData this is contained in a .js script file and how do I call it?

```
$(window).load(function () {
   Main.init();
});

window.Main = {
sync: function () {
    alert("sync");
},
init: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.displayDialog();
},

displayDialog: function () {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 240,
        width: 500,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Sync Data": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                Main.sync();
                syncData();
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                alert("Cancel");
            }
        }
    });
};
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
     <title>Pay Items Amounts</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--<script src="Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/PayItemAmounts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/spin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/syncData.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <nav>
    </nav>
    <section class="dialog-confirmation">
        <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Sync Data?" style="display:none">
            <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
            <label id="dialog-message"></label> </p>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>

JAVASCRIPT syncData.js FILE:
syncData: function () {
    alert("sync");
}
```

Comment: As presented (at the bottom of your HTML code block) that `syncData.js` file is a syntax error. It's like part of the inside of an object initializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `syncData()` because you haven't defined a function called `syncData`.

This (since it not inside an object literal definition):

```
syncData: function () {
    alert("sync");
}
```

…is a syntax error.

You should have:

```
function syncData () {
    alert("sync");
}
```

or, if you really want a function expression:

```
var syncData = function () {
    alert("sync");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect.

```
function syncData() {
  // whatever
}
```

What you've got should, I think, be a syntax error. The label ("syncData:") is OK but it's useless.  The function declaration is missing a name, so that's what (I think) will generate an error.